# How to change and track changes to a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found it really hard to come up with a question title for this one so I apologise that it's fairly cryptic but I'll try explain better there.

Basically part of an app I'm developing involves placing 'placeholders' in a textarea and then modifying those placeholders outside of the textarea.

For example:

```
This is the <first> placeholder. This is the <second> placeholder.
This is the <first> placeholder again.
```

Basically i have JS that detects these placeholders and creates input boxes to hold the text. So there would be an input text box for **first** and one for **second**.

What I want to achieve is when I type a value into the textbox it changes the placeholder in the textarea to the content being typed into the textbox. Think sublime text editor's snippets for a textarea.

I'm trying to figure out how I can track the placeholders in the text area. For example if a placeholder was `<first_name>` and i started typing into the placeholders textbox 'Billy'. I could easily change the placeholder by using a string replace function. However now the placeholder `<first_name>` doesn't exist in the textarea and so now I can't go back and change it. I need to have a way of tracking these placeholders whilst they are changing.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Can you show some code please

Comment: Do you have to use a `textarea`? This would be so much easier with `span` elements inside a `div`!

Comment: @Dolours I don't have any good yet. I'm trying to problem solve before writing any

Comment: @BenM I'd really like to use a textarea if possible as I'm like it to be really easy to them modify the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not bound to a `<textarea>` element, you can try with a simple div with the attribute `contenteditable="true"`. This way you can use some `<span>` to mark all the placeholders.

I set up a [demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JeryT/), try it.

Comment: thanks this works great. (I had to change the code a bit; the value of v1 was being passed into v2). I totally forgot about the contenteditable attribute!

Answer (score 0):

Using an element with `contenteditable="true"` would be easier for that task, because you could represent placeholders as `span` elements and you would then only have to retrieve them by `id` or any other unique `attribute` to update their content.

If you **have** to use a `textarea` and the users can only modify it's content using external inputs, maybe you could initially track the `index` of each placeholers and their `length` and keep those synchronized as values are changed.

You could then easily replace content in the `textarea`. For example, if the placeholder starts at 15 and has a length of 13.

```
    var string = 'this is a test {placeholder} bla bla bla',
        placeHolderIndex = 15,
        placeHolderLength = 13;

    string = 
        string.substring(0, placeHolderIndex) 
        + 'new value' 
        + string.substring(placeHolderIndex + placeHolderLength);

//update indexes of every placeholders that comes after this 
//one and update the content length of this placeholder.
```

Obviously, you don't want to hardcode any values and you will want to handle this process in a dynamic way, but that's just an example.

*NOTE: I guess users can modify the `textarea` content if you're using one. In that case, it would make things a bit more complicated, because you would have to update the `index` of the placeholders for every modifications the user does and you would also have to prevent them from editing the placeholders-mapped text directly.*